# trying to catch all return paths in this block of code

Tags: c#

I hope this has not been asked before, is there a way to highlight all of the return paths where a return statement should go in a method? Cause I have this rather long block of code with may paths and I still have not found every path on it. (I think it would be a helpful tool) cheers.

```
 static double findconversion(int menuOption, int submenuOption) {

        if (menuOption == 1) {

            if (submenuOption == 1) {

                    Console.Write("\nYou chose to convert Celcius to Fahrenheit" +            "\nEnter the number that you want to convert, (between -500 and 500)"
                        + "\nOr enter 0 to return to the previous menu: ");
                    double celnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 


                if (celnum == 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou cancelled your selection"); return celnum;

                } else if ((-500 > celnum) || (celnum > 500)) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nchoose a number between -500 to 500 please"); 

                    findconversion(menuOption, submenuOption); return celnum;

                } else if ((-500 <= celnum) && (celnum <= 500)) {

                    double result = Celsiusandfahrenheit(celnum, submenuOption);

                    if (submenuOption == 1) {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n   " + celnum + (" degrees celcius converted to fahrenheit is: {0:0.00} degrees fahrenheit"), result);
                        return celnum;
                    } else if (submenuOption == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n   " + celnum + (" degrees fahrenheit converted to celcius is: {0:0.00} degrees celcius"), result);
                        return celnum;
                    } return celnum;
                }

            } else if (submenuOption == 2) {
                Console.Write("\nYou chose to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius" + "\nEnter the number that you want to convert, (between -500 and 500)"
                    + "\nOr enter 0 to return to the previous menu: "); 


                double celnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 




                if (celnum == 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou cancelled your selection"); return celnum;

                } else if ((-500 > celnum) || (celnum > 500)) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nchoose a number between -500 to 500 please");


                    findconversion(menuOption, submenuOption); return celnum;
                } else if ((-500 <= celnum) && (celnum <= 500)) {

                    double result = Celsiusandfahrenheit(celnum, submenuOption);
                    if (submenuOption == 2) {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n   " + celnum + (" degrees fahrenheit converted to celcius is: {0:0.00} degrees celcius"), result); return celnum;
                    }




                } return celnum;


            } 

        } else if (menuOption == 2) {

            if (submenuOption == 1) {
                Console.Write("\nYou chose to convert centimetres to feet and inches" + "\nEnter the number that you want to convert to feet and inches, (between -500 and 500)."
                    + "\nOr enter 0 to return to the previous menu: ");
                double celnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

                if (celnum == 0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYou cancelled your selection"); return celnum;

                } else if ((-500 > celnum) || (celnum > 500)) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nchoose a number between -500 to 500 please"); 

                    findconversion(menuOption, submenuOption); return celnum;

                } else if ((-500 <= celnum) && (celnum <= 500)) {


                    double result = cmsandfeet(celnum, submenuOption);
                    // double result1 = cmsandinches(centnum, submenuOption, empty);
                    result = Math.Floor(result);
                    double result1 = ((celnum - (result * 30.48)) / 2.54);
                    if (submenuOption == 1) { Console.WriteLine("\n   " + celnum + (" centimetres converted to feet and inches is: {0:0} feet and {1:0.00} inches"), result, result1); } return celnum;


                } 

                return celnum;
            } 

        }
    }
```

Comment: No such thing exists. The correct approach is to refactor this horrific method into many smaller ones.

Comment: what do you mean with return paths? the return statements?

Comment: If you have a code path that doesn't return a value in a method whose signature guarantees a value will be returned, I can't think of any way to write your code such that the compiler won't slap your hand and refuse to build.

Comment: Where the `return` is placed changes the meaning of the method, and only the developer (i.e. you) is qualified to make decisions on meaning.

Comment: thanks guys, i know it is a big block of code. If I put a return statement at all return points then surely it should return right? I just cannot see where I am missing the return statements. It has 2 on the error on the bottom of visual, so I guess it is at 2 points, but I put returns at the end of every if statement and still not luck!! - Branko thanks (But all paths need a return statement don't they? - i cannot choose where they go) can anyone see from looking at ir where i am missing the return? Daniel - just because it is big does not mean it cannot work though right?

Comment: @jon - It might help if you format your code the correct way.  Do you use a good editor that will fix the format problems for you?  I mean the compiler will tell you where your missing a `return.`

Answer (score 1):

I started answering this as a comment, but I realized there may be enough instructive content to warrant a full answer.

As the developer, you're responsible for knowing the flow of logic, and knowing where all the paths in your code are.  As a very general rule of thumb, you want to look carefully at every `if`/`else` structure, and decide: Is the end of this conditional block a place I return from, or will the logic continue after this?  Step through each possibility, and see for yourself if you're landing in the right area.

You can help yourself be a better coder by formatting well.  For example, at the end of your "celnum between -500 and 500" blocks, you have this:

```
if (submenuOption == 1) { Console.WriteLine("\n   " + celnum + (" centimetres converted to feet and inches is: {0:0} feet and {1:0.00} inches"), result, result1); } return celnum;
```

That's poor for many reasons, least of which is that last `return celnum` at the end of a really long line.  That executes regardless of the conditional, but I don't know that without studying carefully.  Instead, this is much more clear:

```
if (submenuOption == 1) { 
    Console.WriteLine("\n   " + celnum + (" centimetres converted to feet and inches is: {0:0} feet and {1:0.00} inches"), result, result1);
}
return celnum;
```

This directly visually shows me that you are returning a value, regardless of the value of submenuOption.

The other thing you have to look at is having a default case, or an "implicit `else`".  You do this in several cases, which is good, (for example, the `return celnum` after the "is it in the range of -500 and 500").  Where you don't do it, which is causing the error, is your outermost conditional.

You have `if submenuOption == 1`, and you have `else if submenuOption == 2`, but you don't have anything after that.  What happens if the submenuOption isn't 1 or 2?  In that case, you don't return anything.  Outside of your known cases, you need a default case - either throw an error, or return a value that indicates there was no good option chosen.  That should fix your compiler issue.